# trying to scraping a page, but there is a missing

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
index_cd = 'KPI200'
page_n = 1
naver_index = 'http://finance.naver.com/sise/sise_index_day.nhn?code' + index_cd + '&page=' + str(page_n)

from urllib.request import urlopen
source = urlopen(naver_index).read()
import bs4
source = bs4.BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
td = source.find_all('td')
len(td)
# /html/body/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]  # this is XPath
source.find_all('table')[0].find_all('tr')[2].find_all('td')[0]
```

I thought the output will be like this: `<td class="date">2020.09.29</td>`

But the result is that this one: `<td class="date"> </td>`

There is a `'\xa0'` between `<td class="date"` and `</td>`.

I need to extract that date. How to solve this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `url` that u have provided. U have missed an `=` after `code`.

Change `naver_index = 'http://finance.naver.com/sise/sise_index_day.nhn?code' + index_cd + '&page=' + str(page_n)` to `naver_index = 'http://finance.naver.com/sise/sise_index_day.nhn?code=' + index_cd + '&page=' + str(page_n)`

This is the working code:

```
index_cd = 'KPI200'
page_n = 1
naver_index = 'http://finance.naver.com/sise/sise_index_day.nhn?code=' + index_cd + '&page=' + str(page_n)

from urllib.request import urlopen
source = urlopen(naver_index).read()
import bs4
source = bs4.BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
td = source.find_all('td')
len(td)
# /html/body/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]  # this is XPath
print(source.find_all('table')[0].find_all('tr')[2].find_all('td')[0])
```

Output:

```
<td class="date">2020.09.29</td>
```

If u only want the date to be displayed, then change the last line to:

```
print(source.find_all('table')[0].find_all('tr')[2].find_all('td')[0].text)
```

Output:

```
2020.09.29
```

Hope that this helps u!

Comment: Oh, I missed that! Thank you!

Comment: YW! A humble request from my side. Could u pls upvote my answer and accept it as the best answer?